# Get custom type back from DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am having a problem with a ComboBoxColumn in my DataGridView. I populate the DataSource of the ComboBoxColumn with a list of an own type and set `DataPropertyName`, `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` accordingly.
Problem is: when I select a different value and select another cell I get an exception because the value of type long cannot be converted back to the object.

The class that is used for the DropDown's values:

```
public class Unit
{
    public long? ID { get; set;}

    public string Name { get; set;}

    public Unit(long id, string name)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

The class that is used for the DataGridView data:

```
public class Data
{
    public long? Amount { get; set; }

    public Unit ChosenUnit { get; set; }

    public Data(long? amount, Unit unit)
    {
        Amount = amount;
        ChosenUnit = unit;
    }
}
```

I'm filling the DropDown and the Grid like this

```
        List<Unit> units = new List<Unit>();
        units.Add(new Unit(1, "grams"));
        units.Add(new Unit(2, "kilograms"));
        units.Add(new Unit(3, "tons"));

        List<Data> data = new List<Data>();
        data.Add(new Data(200, units[0]));
        data.Add(new Data(2, units[1]));
        data.Add(new Data(1, units[2]));

        gridData.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        gridData.Columns.Add("Amount", "Amount");
        gridData.Columns["Amount"].DataPropertyName = "Amount";

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cboColUnits = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        cboColUnits.Items.AddRange(units.ToArray());
        cboColUnits.HeaderText = "Unit";
        cboColUnits.DataPropertyName = "ChosenUnit";
        cboColUnits.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cboColUnits.ValueMember = "ID";
        cboColUnits.ValueType = typeof(long?);

        gridData.Columns.Add(cboColUnits);
        gridData.DataSource = data;
```

Filling data into the grid view works fine, but when i select a diffent unit i get the following exception:

[image: exception]

What can I do to solve this problem? Do I need to implement certain event handlers or create custom edit control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property to the `Unit` class as a self-reference - TIP: also override the `Equals` method. Then Set that new property as your `ValueMember`:

```
public class Unit
{
    public long? ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Unit Self { get { return this; } }

    public Unit(long id, string name)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj != null && obj is Unit)
        {
            if ((obj as Unit).ID == this.ID && (obj as Unit).Name == this.Name) //* See Footnote
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return base.Equals(obj);
    }
}
```

<sub>* In your `Equals` overridden method don't forget to account for your nullable type checks, which I didn't code for brevity - but you get the idea.</sub>

---

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cboColUnits = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
cboColUnits.Items.AddRange(units.ToArray());
cboColUnits.HeaderText = "Unit";
cboColUnits.DataPropertyName = "ChosenUnit";
cboColUnits.DisplayMember = "Name";
cboColUnits.ValueMember = "Self";
cboColUnits.ValueType = typeof(Unit);
```